# Change user input to lowercase

Tags: java

I am really new to learning Java and I am trying to change the user input to lowercase (or uppercase). However it isn't work. Any suggestion?

```
    protected String nextMove()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter move");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).toUpperCase();

    while (!in.hasNext("['a','b','c']"))
    {
     String move;
     System.out.println("That is not a valid guess");
     move = in.nextLine();
     in.close();
     return move;
 }
return nextMove();
}
```

Comment: You are attempting to put the Scanner to upper case, I don't think it likes it much.

Comment: Ah okay, so it's as simple as changing it and putting the (toUpperCase) on a different line?

Comment: `  while (!in.hasNext("['a','b','c']"))
  {
   String move;
   System.out.println("That is not a valid guess");
   move = in.nextLine();
   in.close();
   return move;
  }
  return nextMove();
 } `  

This is the following code

Comment: @Brigzy97: no, calling `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` on a **different object**. Not on the Scanner but on the String.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34681199/edit).

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the heads up about code in comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scanner is for getting input, not for translating or transforming it, and your code shouldn't even compile since you're calling a Scanner method that doesn't exist. You instead want to transform the String obtained.

You could simply do:

```
String myLowerCaseInput = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Edit: as a side note, I highly doubt that you will want to create the Scanner object in this method, since you should only create **one** Scanner object based on `System.in`. If need be, pass that Scanner into this method using a parameter.

```
protected String nextMove(Scanner in) {
    System.out.print("Please enter move: ");
    return in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
}
```

or better...

```
private static String nextMove(Scanner in) {
    String input = "";
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter move: ");
        input = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    } while (input.isEmpty() || input.length() != 1 || !"abc".contains(input));
    return input;
}
```

Comment: So is it because of the line that I am doing it on then?

Comment: @Brigzy97: the Scanner is for getting input, not for translating or transforming it. You want to transform the String obtained.

Comment: I think that the person who set me this task did want me to do the Scanner like that. But I will try it and see what they say. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Brigzy97: oops, bugs fixed.

Comment: I don't want you thinking that I'm just looking for code, but where in this would you then put a error message like I had before?

Comment: Inside the do-while loop, immediately after getting the input, to an input validity check, and post the error message if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);      
 while (!in.hasNext("['a','b','c']")){
  String upercase = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
   ...
```